# What are some machine learning problems that can be attacked with continuous multiobjective optimization?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization, nonlinear-regression, gradient-descent

I am working on continuous vector optimization, and hence continuous multiobjective optimization is a particular case. I am interested in finding applications in machine learning for this problems. Is there any context on which you could use Pareto/weak Pareto optimal points to learn the optimal parameters? I was wondering whether there exists something like a multiobjective version of logistic regression, least squares or SVMs. So, the idea is to select a Pareto point of a function $f$ which is decomposable as
$$f(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(\theta),$$ where $f_i:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k.$
 Any pointer to the literature will also be very helpful.